# Periodic Windows Server Based Processes

Tags: scheduled-tasks, monitoring, windows-server

I have some custom programs I've written to do various maintenance/monitoring tasks that I run periodically (some every few minutes, some as little as once a day).  Is it a better practice to run them out of the task scheduler, or to run them as a windows service (triggered by an embedded timer object)?

Comment: I've been using the windows service method--but seems to be a lot of programmatic overhead without a lot of gain.  Installation of new versions is a little more complicated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an interesting article about services vs. sheduled tasks.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx

I think for simple/one-off type scheduled processing, it's easier to just write a console app and run it as windows scheduled task.

However, most of the time, I end up writing a service, just so all of our services run the same way.  Like Martin said [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is really powerful for writing scheduled services, and gives you more flexibility than plain scheduled tasks.

Comment: Great link.  Thanks.  Clearly for what I'm using the windows scheduler is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I somehow assumed you were looking for a .NET solution. If not, then please disregard my answer.

---

If you want to use your own windows service, then have a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html):

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open
>   source job scheduling system that can
>   be used from smallest apps to large
>   scale enterprise systems.

With this library you get the flexibility of the windows task scheduler for free, but can run your own service.